# Grapes on the vine

Tags: design

I'd like to build a lego winery, similar to
[this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/exesandbox/50903338837/)
It looks like he's using the [purple ice cream scoops](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6254&name=Food%20&%20Drink%20Ice%20Cream%20Scoops&category=%5BFood%20&%20Drink%5D#T=S&C=89&O=%7B%22color%22:%2289%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)  for grapes, right?
How do you think those are attaching to the plants?
How might I create something more like a rectangular vine/trellis area with vines and grapes on the vines?
My current plan involves using a [trellis fence](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3185&name=Fence%201%20x%204%20x%202&category=%5BFence%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) and [vines](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=16981&C=0#T=S&C=0&O=%7B%22color%22:%220%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) somehow, but I'm not sure about the specifics.  Any suggestions?

[image: MOC copied here in case the original goes dark]

Comment: could you possible thread a hose, soft axle 7L through a trellis fence and then plug the ice cream scoops onto the other end?

Comment: There are a lot more pictures in the [author's Flickr album for this model](https://flickr.com/photos/exesandbox/albums/72157718139635096).

Answer (score 6):

Leaves and grapes are attached using [Bar 1L with Clip Mechanical Claw](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48729b&name=Bar%20%20%201L%20with%20Clip%20Mechanical%20Claw,%20Cut%20Edges%20and%20Hole%20on%20Side&category=%5BBar%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the help Hugo. Can you elaborate on that just a bit?

Comment: Leaves holes are pushed into the bar part of "Bar 1L with Clip Mechanical Claw". The clip part is attached to the redish brown horizontal 3L bar that serve as support. Same thing for the grapes. And then you can give them the desire angle.

Comment: Thanks hugo.  I dont think the clip part will clip to a mesh fence right?

Comment: No it won't. An alternative if you really want to use a mesh fence is to use a "Carrot Top / Twig" or" Plant Stem with 3 Leaves and Bottom Pin" instead of the "Bar 1L with Clip Mechanical Claw". Simply push the bar part through the fence holes then push it in the leaves hole.

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit bulky (and my apologies for not verifying feasibility: my LEGO are all in storage for an upcoming move), but might something like this work, albeit bulkily?
1.) take a 1x1 brick with two SNOT studs on opposing sides and turn it upside down
2.) place a leaf on the top (hole end/"bottom" 'cause the 1x1's inverted) and one on one of the SNOT (side) studs
3.) place the grapes on the stud of the inverted 1x1
4.) Use the remaining SNOT (side) stud and attached the plant to the fence.  I believe that the diamond lattice can fit a stud.
5.) separately, wrap a string with studs on either end around various elements and the fence to create the vines.  (Though I like Monte Gardner's idea of hoses much better.  :))

Comment: Is there a brick with studs on both sides?

Comment: Yes, 47905.  https://brickset.com/parts/design-47905 .  You could also use one with four SNOT studs if you wanted more vegetation, https://brickset.com/parts/design-4733 .